# How do I determine if a coordinate is in the currently visible map region?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0, mapkit

I have a list of several hundred locations and only want to display an MKPinAnnotation for those locations currently on the screen. The screen starts with the user's current location within a 2-mile radius.  Of course, the user can scroll, and zoom on the screen.  Right now, I wait for a map update event, then  loop through my location list, and check the coordinates like this:

```
-(void)mapViewDidFinishLoadingMap:(MKMapView *)mapView {
  CGPoint point;
  CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;

  . . .
  /* in location loop */
  coordinate.latitude = [nextLocation getLatitude];
  coordinate.longitude = [nextLocation getLongitude];

  /* Determine if point is in view. Is there a better way then this? */
  point = [mapView convertCoordinate:coordinate toPointToView:nil];
  if( (point.x > 0) && (point.y>0) ) {
    /* Add coordinate to array that is later added to mapView */
  }
```

So I am asking to convert the coordinate where the point would be on the screen(unless I misunderstand this method which is very possible).  If the coordinate isn't on the screen, then I never add it to the mapView.

So my question is, is this the correct way to determine if a location's lat/long would appear in the current view and should be added to the mapView?  Or should I be doing this in a different way?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. For some reason, all of my objects seem to match. The values of most of the x and y's are very high. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure, I am on a trip at the moment and don't have access to a Mac. The first thing that comes to mind is to check the map region. But even then if the point isn't on the screen(at least in my testing) the convertCoordinate method always returned 0. I'll check it out once I am back in front of my mac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a little bit of reading I can't find anything that says this is a bad idea. I've done a bit of testing in my app and I always get correct results. The app loads much quicker when I only add coordinates that will show up in the currently visible map region instead of all the 300+ coordinates at once.

What I was looking for was a method like  [mapView isCoordinateInVisibleRegion:myCoordinate], but so far this method is quick and seems accurate.

I've also changed the title to read "in the visible map region" instead of the previous because I think the incorrect title may have confused my meaning.

Comment: Can you please provide some sample code for [mapView isCoordinateInVisibleRegion:myCoordinate]?.So,I can know how can i use in my app.

Answer (score 7):

In your code, you should pass a view for the `toPointToView:` option. I gave it my `mapView`. You have to specify an upper bound for the x and y too.

Here's some code which worked for me (told me the currently visible annotations on my map, while looping through the annotation):

```
for (Shop *shop in self.shops) {
    ShopAnnotation *ann = [ShopAnnotation annotationWithShop:shop];
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:ann];

    CGPoint annPoint = [self.mapView convertCoordinate:ann.coordinate 
            toPointToView:self.mapView];

    if (annPoint.x > 0.0 && annPoint.y > 0.0 && 
            annPoint.x < self.mapView.frame.size.width && 
            annPoint.y < self.mapView.frame.size.height) {
        NSLog(@"%@ Coordinate: %f %f", ann.title, annPoint.x, annPoint.y);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I know this is an old thread, not sure what was available back then... But you should rather do:

```
// -- Your previous code and CLLocationCoordinate2D init --
MKMapRect visibleRect = [mapView visibleMapRect];
if(MKMapRectContainsPoint(visibleRect, MKMapPointForCoordinate(coordinate))) {

    // Do your stuff

}
```

No need to convert back to the screen space.
Also I am not sure the reason why you are trying to do this, I think this is strange to not add annotations when they are not on the screen... MapKit already optimizes this and only creates (and recycles) annotation views that are visible.

Comment: Man I remember this project :) I don't remember the details that far back however. I think the issue is my app loaded much faster if I only displayed coordinates that should be shown. Maybe mapkit wasn't optimized yet? I think this was ios4.

Comment: Yes I thought it was worth mentioning that this might not be the way to go nowadays... Thanks for replying I appreciate.

Comment: I think you should have used `MKMapPointForCoordinate(<#CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate#>)` instead or `coordinate` directly.