# Core Location and UISearch bar

Tags: iphone

I would like to develop an iPhone application and I have a problem witch is:

1. a have a web services witch deliver for me the longitude an altitude of my objects.
2. a would like to use a search bar and a map, when I tape for example Paris, I would like to see all my objects in the map.

Is this possible to do? If YES how I can  proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Store your objects from the webservice.
2. Search for a location.
3. Display the search location in the map.
4. To show annotations in the map with your objects, see [how-do-i-determine-if-a-coordinate-is-in-the-currently-visible-map-region](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197398/how-do-i-determine-if-a-coordinate-is-in-the-currently-visible-map-region)

Comment: ok thanks, but my problem is for example i am in London, and i tape Manchester and i get all my objects in a map. is this possible with this solution

Comment: Yes because you can convert coordinates in map point, and with map points, ckeck if they are in the map .