# MKAnnotation only within region

Tags: iphone, mkannotation, region

How can I only load the annotations that are within the displayed region? At the moment I load all Annotation with this method

```
- (void)reloadAnnotatons
{
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    request.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Cave" inManagedObjectContext:self.context];
    request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(latitude > 0) AND (longitude > 0)"];

    [self.mapView addAnnotations:[self.context executeFetchRequest:request error:NULL]];
}
```

Any ideas or good documents on how I could remove all annotations that are outside the display and load the others?

Thanks a lot

EDIT:

I have actually found a solution but it does not perfectly work somehow. I check if region has changed

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self reloadAnnotatons];
}
```

Then I get max/min lat/long and pull it out of coredata

```
- (void)reloadAnnotatons
{
    double minLat = self.mapView.region.center.latitude - (self.mapView.region.span.latitudeDelta / 2);
    double maxLat = self.mapView.region.center.latitude + (self.mapView.region.span.latitudeDelta / 2);
    double minLon = self.mapView.region.center.longitude - (self.mapView.region.span.longitudeDelta / 2);
    double maxLon = self.mapView.region.center.longitude + (self.mapView.region.span.longitudeDelta / 2);

    NSLog(@"%f %f %f %f",minLat,maxLat,minLon,maxLon);

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    request.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Cave" inManagedObjectContext:self.context];
    request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(latitude > %f AND latitude < %f) AND (longitude > %f AND longitude < %f)",minLat,maxLat,minLon,maxLon];

    //NSLog(@"%@",[self.context executeFetchRequest:request error:NULL]);

    [self.mapView addAnnotations:[self.context executeFetchRequest:request error:NULL]];
}
```

Only problem is that it only finds the annotations if you zoom in a certain level which is strange. For example

When I zoomed out quite far it has a wide range from min to max. Order is minLat,maxLat,minLong,MaxLong

```
2011-09-07 08:48:15.907 CaveConditions[9028:707] 43.930069 50.169209 3.078351 10.207223
2011-09-07 08:48:15.914 CaveConditions[9028:707] (
)
```

As soon as I zooom in it does get the objects. Allthough it should already find it before.

```
2011-09-07 08:48:35.363 CaveConditions[9028:707] 46.277977 48.327505 5.453421 7.806564
2011-09-07 08:48:35.376 CaveConditions[9028:707] (
    "<Cave: 0x1d8710> (entity: Cave; id: 0x1cdd10 <x-coredata://738720B4-DCF4-40BA-BD83-A459CECE5F29/Cave/p2> ; data: <fault>)",
    "<Cave: 0x1941c0> (entity: Cave; id: 0x1d1e70 <x-coredata://738720B4-DCF4-40BA-BD83-A459CECE5F29/Cave/p47> ; data: <fault>)",
    "<Cave: 0x190200> (entity: Cave; id: 0x1e62b0 <x-coredata://738720B4-DCF4-40BA-BD83-A459CECE5F29/Cave/p57> ; data: <fault>)",
    "<Cave: 0x1e4960> (entity: Cave; id: 0x1a1560 <x-coredata://738720B4-DCF4-40BA-BD83-A459CECE5F29/Cave/p67> ; data: <fault>)",
```

It actually finds it when I sql directly the sqllite db with

```
SELECT * 
FROM caves
WHERE (
latitude > 43.930069
AND latitude < 50.169209
)
AND (
longitude > 3.078351
AND longitude < 10.207223
)
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually find the solution to all of that. I track if the region has changed

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self reloadAnnotatons];
}
```

Then I get max/min lat/long and pull it out of coredata

```
- (void)reloadAnnotatons
{
    double minLat = self.mapView.region.center.latitude - (self.mapView.region.span.latitudeDelta / 2);
    double maxLat = self.mapView.region.center.latitude + (self.mapView.region.span.latitudeDelta / 2);
    double minLon = self.mapView.region.center.longitude - (self.mapView.region.span.longitudeDelta / 2);
    double maxLon = self.mapView.region.center.longitude + (self.mapView.region.span.longitudeDelta / 2);


    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    request.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Cave" inManagedObjectContext:self.context];
    request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(latitude > %lf AND latitude < %lf) AND (longitude > %lf AND longitude < %lf)",minLat,maxLat,minLon,maxLon];


    [self.mapView addAnnotations:[self.context executeFetchRequest:request error:NULL]];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As default MapView loads only the annotations that are within your display(i.e, Onscreen). If you just move the screen you can reuse the Annotations with Reuse identifier for annotations. So technically you dont need remove annotations that are out of your display.

Info from Apple doc

> Because annotation views are needed only when they are onscreen, the
>   MKMapView class provides a mechanism for queueing annotation views
>   that are not in use. Annotation views with a reuse identifier can be
>   detached and queued internally by the map view when they move off
>   screen. This feature improves memory use by keeping only a small
>   number of annotation views in memory at once and by recycling the
>   views you do have. It also improves scrolling performance by
>   alleviating the need to create new views while the map is scrolling.

Comment: I agree with that. But I still load all from CoreData in the beginning. I would like to limit that as well if possible

Comment: What i can suggest is you have to check that the coordinate returned from Coredata is visble in the current mapview region if so add the coordinate to annotations. If my assumption is correct then visit this link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197398/how-do-i-determine-if-a-coordinate-is-in-the-currently-visible-map-region

Comment: I actually found a solution. I edited my previous post. Only problem is that it does not perfectly work. Any idea?